# Common Event Handlers in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, event-handling, this

I have around 10 buttons on my form and I want them to call the same Click event handler.

But for that I need the Event handler to be generalized and we don't have "this" keyword in VB.NET to refer to the control that caused the event.

How do I implement the functionality of "this" keyword in VB.NET?

I want to be able to write an Event handler that does the following:

```
Private Sub cmdButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdButton1.Click

    currentTag = this.Tag

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I implement the functionality of "this" keyword in VB.NET?

`this` is called `Me` in VB. However, this has got nothing to do with your code and refers to the containing class, in your case most probably the current `Form`. You need to access the `sender` object parameter, after casting it to `Control`:

```
currentTag = DirectCast(sender, Control).Tag
```

Comment: It makes me wonder why sender isn't declared as a control in .NET... I suppose because the sender could also be a Form or something.

Comment: R. Bemrose: because this general method signature for event handlers isn't only used for Control events! In fact, it should be used for *all* events. Past versions of .NET required a common signature for lack of contravariant delegates. This is no longer true in the current versions of VB and C#.

Answer (score 1):

In [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), `Me` is the equivalent to C#'s `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `Me` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET `this` is referred as `me`, and the solution for your second question regarding handlers for VB.NET is: You can add `Handles` at the end of a `Private Sub` statement, like:

```
Private Sub cmdButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles cmdButton1.Click, 'cmdButton2.click, cmdButton3.click'

    currentTag = this.Tag

End Sub
```